# Trouble importing .pskx file to blender

Tags: import

So, I will list the steps that I did to get to the point where I am having the error.

1) Download latest Umodel and use it to extract model from my game of choice, namely, NekopaLive, which runs on Unreal 4.

[image]

2) Download latest version of blender (2.7) Launch and delete all objects within default scene. Save scene as default.

3) Enable the Addon Script for .pskx imports from google searches.
[image]
4) Attempt to import .pskx file. Now, I play a lot of fighting games, so believe me when I say I can see very fast things.  **The model flashes on screen for a frame, looking just like it does in Umodel, and then it goes back to the empty scene in blender, where I get the error**:

[image]

Or written out:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\dilydaly\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_import_scene_unreal_pskx.py", line 658, in execute
>       getInputFilenamepsk(self, self.filepath, self.importmesh, self.importbone, self.bDebugLogPSK, self.importmultiuvtextures)
>     File "C:\Users\dilydaly\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_import_scene_unreal_pskx.py", line 598, in getInputFilenamepsk
>       pskxImport(filename, importmesh, importbone, bDebugLogPSK, importmultiuvtextures)
>     File "C:\Users\dilydaly\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_import_scene_unreal_pskx.py", line 211, in pskxImport
>       indata = unpack('64s6i', pskxFile.read(88))
>   struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 88
>
> location:  unknown location :-1

At this point, I am stuck. I am relatively new to porting models, and have never worked with Unreal porting before, so I would like to know what I would need to do next to get this model working in blender.

Could someone please explain to me what is going wrong here?

The part that stands out to me is "struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 88" but I don't know what that actually means in terms of the model data.

I appreciate the time taken in advance to reply!

Comment: Check the outliner in datablock mode, there may be a mesh and armature created before the importer crashed that is not linked to the scene.